# Smooth movement of JButton on an action

Tags: java, swing, animation, concurrency, jbutton

How can I smoothly move the JButton if action performed (eg the button is pushed). Here's my example but it doesnt work propely:

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
   for(int i = 0; i<50; i++){
          ww.button.setLocation(ww.button.getLocation().x+1, ww.button.getLocation().y);//ww is a JFrame child
      try {
        Thread.sleep(20);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
```

After action performed I get a delay in 20*50 ms and button location set in previous loc + 50px, without intermediate locations.

Comment: try to work with Layout.

Comment: What is ww? Also did are you using polymorphism for your button. Could you show a little more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always try to avoid `Thread` while working with Swing. In your code it will make main EDT thread to sleep and that's why you are not able to view intermediate locations. Try this with using [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) and you will get it working as intended. Take a look here: [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and also try using [Swing workers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Comment: You should also beware that if you are using a layout manager (and you should), the layout manager will want to move the button back to where it thinks it should when the parent container is invalidated, this may result in undesirable actions

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes when container revalidates/repaint it self, it might change the locations of its child as per its policy.

Comment: Sorry Harry, that wasn't "at" you per say, just "additional" :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah I know :)

Comment: this code works fine in win xp:
 `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    for(int i = 0; i<50; i++){
    ActionListener task = new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    ww.button.setLocation(ww.button.getLocation().x+1, ww.button.getLocation().y);
   }
  };
  Timer timer = new Timer(20, task);
  timer.setRepeats(false);
  timer.start();
    }
    
   }`
but it doesnt work in win7(the button jumps from first position to last). I suppose that 'for' cycle is not suitable here, is it?

Comment: @hunterra you are creating new Timer everytime, you should not do this. Create one single timer that repeats on desired time interval and in its action method do button shifting work.

Comment: @Harry Joy, thank you for your help.
 The point of this example was to shift the button smothly on several px and then stop. If I create single timer with `setRepeats(true)` it would shift button infinitely. How can I set the amount of repeats?

Comment: @hunterra timer also has stop method, which you can use to stop after you shift your button upto few pixels.

Comment: @HarryJoy, thank you. Finally I did it. First of all I should add ActionListener to the button and put there start() method of the Timer. After that I should add AncestorListener to track the movement of the button and run stop() method when necessary. That was hard =)

Comment: @hunterra Good to hear that. :)